# Nokogiri group flat structure

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an HTML structure like:

```
<div class='content'>
 <h2>Title</h2>
 <p>Some content for Title</p>
 <h2>Another Title</h2> 
 <p>Content for Another Title</p>
 <p>Some more content for Another title</p>
 <h2>Third</h2>
 <p>Third Content</p>
</div>
```

I am trying to write code to output:

```
Title
 - Some content for Title
Another Title
 - Content for Another Title
 - Some more content for Another title
Third
 - Third Content
```

I've never used Nokogiri until five minutes ago, all I can come up with so far is:

```
content = doc.at_css('.content')
content.css('h2').each do |node|
  puts node.text
end
content.css('p').each do |node|
  puts " - "
  puts node.text
end
```

This obviously doesn't group the pieces together. How can I achieve my required grouping with Nokogiri?

Comment: You've used it for less than 10 minutes at this point, and you're already asking for help? Have you read [the tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials) and looked through the many [questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby+nokogiri) here on Stack Overflow in the remaining five minutes?

Comment: I usually agree with this sentiment but grouping sibling elements like that is tricky. And he did show code.

Comment: @theTinMan no. Instead I spent my time working on things where I could be productive, and eventually my question was answered. Instead of spending minutes, maybe hours reading tutorials, I invested a few seconds to ask my question, and got my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, here's one:

```
doc.at_css('.content').element_children.each do |node|
  puts(node.name == "h2" ? node.text : " - #{node.text}")  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.
Here's how I would fix it.

```
content.css('h2').each do |node|
  puts node.text
  while node = node.at('+ p')
    puts " - #{node.text}"
  end
end
```

`+ p` means the next (adjacent) `p`